# Divide Owner RBAC Role of Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac, azure-rbac

I am trying to divide the Azure Owner RBAC role between IAM actions and Other Actions, is it possible if yes then please help.

I have tried to list out all the actions of all the Azure RBAC roles and tried to distinguish between IAM and Other actions but this is not a good practice i know, even i have tried to list out actions of Owner role which is "*". i have tried 100's of websites as well for the solutions but dint work for me

Comment: what do you mean `IAM actions and Other Actions`?

Comment: i meant i'll divide the Owner's Role in two new role, First will do all the AD related activities and Second will do all the activities other than AD,

Comment: The `AD related activities` you mean like create/delete role assignments? As I know,  the `Owner` just have several permissions related to AD. It is for the subscription, not the AAD tenant.

Comment: yes that's correct and i am wondering i.e. what are all  the AD related actions owner got

Comment: well, if so, I think you can use the [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor), compare to `Owner`, it can do anything as the Owner but not manage the access to resources(the AD related thing you said).

Comment: And if you want to divide the Owner's permissions in two, I think it does not make sense, because once your custom role has the permission to manage the access to resources, he can assign other permissions to anyone like his another account.

Comment: ya exactly, this is what i am looking for, because i want to take control of all the manage access and this will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I think you can use the [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor), compared to Owner, it can do anything as the Owner but not manage the access to resources(the AD related thing you said).

For the AD related thing of `Owner`, you could just check the `NotActions` of `Contributor`.

[image]

And if you want to divide the Owner's permissions in two, I think it does not make sense, because once your custom role has the permission to manage the access to resources, he can assign other roles(e.g. `Owner`) to anyone like himself.

So in your case, you could just assign the `Owner` to the user who should need the most permissions,  assign the `Contributor` to the user that you don't want to give the permissions of AD related thing.

Comment: Thanks Joy,it helps, i have followed the different approach but it's a time taking process, i have been through all the permissions of owner's role, identified the IAM related action from them  and tagged them with the new custom role.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Azure RABC role is used to manage azure resource. Regarding how to manage actions in Azure AD, Azure provides other roles to control it. For more details, please refer to

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles

Comment: yes, I have gone through these docs before but it doesn't fit with my requirement

Comment: @Anshul if you do not want someone to manage access, you can assign Contributor or Read role to the person